# how to change the Inkscape default export color from yellow to white?

Tags: linux, graphics, export, inkscape

Hi
    This might be a very stupid question. I am using export of 'Inkscape' to convert the svg file to png. As I am using the transparent backgroung the color of background is automatically yellow. I want to change this default colour to white

Comment: This question is better suited to SuperUser.com

Comment: thanks birryree. I have posted it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake. as the background was transparent. It depends which image viewer are you using. While displaying everybody has its own color. In general, at linux i found it to be yellow and in windows white.

I am sorry for asking a stupid question.